# What are the drawbacks of using a C library using `extern "C"` vs a native C++ library?

Tags: c++

I've been told that it's always better to use C++ libraries instead of C however it's never been explained why.

Is it better to use C++ libraries vs C libraries and if so why?

Are there any common problems that are encountered when using C libraries in C++?

Comment: Who told you that?

Comment: @NeilButterworth People at local C++ meetups

Comment: In my experience, for my requirements, it has often been better to use C libraries over C++ ones, since C++ libraries often don't let you control allocations as much and use exceptions (I work in the game industry). How about you judge yourself which library you need?

Comment: So why didn't you get them to explain their (incorrect, IMHO) thinking?

Comment: You use the libraries that best fulfill your needs. Any blanket statement one way or the other cannot be true.

Comment: @BaummitAugen "blanket statements are never true" - I like that :)

Comment: I see one: if you inject code inside your c library, and if you can not recompile it with the appropriate flags, the code you inject (for exemple by passing a function pointer) should not throw.

Comment: Yet, it is better to use C++ libraries. C++ has features (i.e. namespaces, references, overloading, templates, stricter type system) that allows C++ library interfaces to be more flexible, easier to use and less error prone at the same time. When using a C library one typically needs to write a dedicated C++ wrapper that will provide handier interface, RAII and careful error handling anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you assumed that the sentence is true. But it's not. There's no  problem/difference in using C++ or C libraries.

The `extern "C"` has a different purpose: When you export a function with C++ compiler, the compiler will "mangle" the exported function name. Like this:

```
int f (void) { return 1; }
```

will be actualy compiled as:

```
int __f_v (void) { return 1; }
```

And this is the way C++ works. If you want to export the same function without mangling (to be used from a C library, for example), then you do:

```
extern "C" int f (void) { return 1; }
```

and then, C++ compiler will "export" this function just the same way the C compiler would do.

Comment: name mangling is even worse, since every compiler can use a different way of mangling function names. meaning that you (very probably) will  not be able to import a c++ library creatad with compiler A in a c++ project created with compiler B. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C.2B.2B) for other details

Comment: yes. but this is not a problem. this is expected to happen.

Comment: I agree with you Wagner, it's not a problem if you know how it works. My comment was just an add to your answer to underline a further problem when using c++ library. in general, if i'm writing with compiler X a library that I know will be shared only by other libraries written with the same compliler (e.g, a Visual studio solution), I prefer using the c++ way to export symbols. I'f I know the library will be consumed by other languages/compilers, I'd go with `extern "C"`

Comment: "export function without mangling" and "export function to be used from a C library" are not the same. Just getting rid of mangling won't be sufficient to let a function be usable from C library. One needs to define a proper C-compatible interface, making all the input and output types compatible with C, carefully dealing with error handling preventing exceptions from getting into caller and converting them to form usable from C (i.e. retval). Also `extern "C"` is not the only way to get rid of mangling, it can be also achieved with module definition file or other exports renaming technics.